# How to align things in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have the following interface:

[image]

and my code is this:

```
child_frame = wx.Frame(self, title="Extension Options", size = (200,400), style=self.child_window_style)
    panel = wx.Panel(child_frame,-1)

    top_title = wx.StaticText(panel, id = -1, label = "Image Extensions")
    middle_title = wx.StaticText(panel, id = -1, label = "Document Extensions")
    bottom_title = wx.StaticText(panel, id = -1, label = "Miscellaneous")

    l = wx.StaticLine(panel, -1, style=wx.LI_HORIZONTAL, size = (200, 1))
    l2 = wx.StaticLine(panel, -1, style=wx.LI_HORIZONTAL, size = (200, 1))

    gif = wx.CheckBox(panel, label = ".gif")
    jpg = wx.CheckBox(panel, label = ".jpg")
    tif = wx.CheckBox(panel, label = ".tiff")
    png = wx.CheckBox(panel, label = ".png")

    word = wx.CheckBox(panel, label = "Word")
    excel = wx.CheckBox(panel, label = "Excel")
    access = wx.CheckBox(panel, label = "Access")
    powerpoint = wx.CheckBox(panel, label = "Power")

    line1_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    line2_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    #Create boxes
    main_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    img_box_title = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)# TITLE BOX
    main_img_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    img_box1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    img_box2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    doc_box_title = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)# TITLE BOX
    main_doc_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    doc_box1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    doc_box2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    misc_box_title = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    #main_misc_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    #Place elements to boxes
    img_box_title.Add(top_title, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)# ASSIGN TITLE
    img_box1.Add(gif, 1, wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL, 5)
    img_box1.Add(jpg, 1, wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL, 5)
    img_box2.Add(tif, 1, wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL, 5)
    img_box2.Add(png, 1, wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL, 5)
    line1_box.Add(l, 0, wx.CENTER, 1)# LINE
    doc_box_title.Add(middle_title, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)# ASSIGN TITLE
    doc_box1.Add(word, 1, wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL, 5)
    doc_box1.Add(access, 1, wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL, 5)
    doc_box2.Add(excel, 1, wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL, 5)
    doc_box2.Add(powerpoint, 1, wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL, 5)
    line2_box.Add(l2, 0, wx.CENTER, 1)# LINE
    misc_box_title.Add(bottom_title, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)# ASSIGN TITLE

    #Place boxes
    main_box.Add(img_box_title, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)# PLACE TITLE
    main_box.Add(main_img_box, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)
    main_img_box.Add(img_box1, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)
    main_img_box.Add(img_box2, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)
    main_box.Add(line1_box, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)# LINE
    main_box.Add(doc_box_title, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)# PACE TITLE
    main_box.Add(main_doc_box, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)
    main_doc_box.Add(doc_box1, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)
    main_doc_box.Add(doc_box2, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)
    main_box.Add(line2_box, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)# LINE
    main_box.Add(misc_box_title, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)# PACE TITLE


    panel.SetSizer(main_box)
    wx.Frame.CenterOnScreen(child_frame)
    child_frame.Show()
```

Is there any way to align the "gif - jpg" with the "word - access"?

I could make it a static window and use pos, but i want to learn to use box sizers as well...

Comment: Try with a [GridBagSizer](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/GridBagSizer.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *convenient* way to align items across sizers, unfortunately. So either you have to use a single sizer including the elements you want to align and everything between them, and in your case `wxGridBagSizer` recommended by @sebdelsol is the only sizer which would work.

Or you could help the sizer layout algorithm slightly. To do this, you need to compute the maximal width of your column(s), by iterating over the results of `GetBestSize()` applied to all the checkboxes in a column. And then you should use [wxSizer::SetItemMinSize()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_sizer.html#a26fc90231667639d5af7c2f8f7b75c80) to set this width for all of them, including the ones in the different sizer.

Notice that independently of the above, your layout could be simplified by using [wxFlexGridSizer](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_flex_grid_sizer.html) instead of so many box sizers.

Answer (score 0):

This was a tricky one (because it is nested so deeply) and required use of [wx.lib.inspection](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Widget%20Inspection%20Tool). See below a hack in the last third of your code, which should allow you to figure out that`wx.ALIGN_CENTER` in the `main_img_box` did override the `wx.ALIGN_LEFT` in the `img_box1/2`. You also need `wx.EXPAND` to allow the elements of `main_img_box` to fill out the proportion of `1` given. `wx.ALL` is required to show the border of `5`.

```
…
# Hack to solve the posters problem. *DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION CODE*
wx.ALIGN_CENTER = wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL

#Place boxes
…
```

Comment: Yes i know, it was confusing to me too, but i had no other option, at least until you guys showed up :P I have already moved with VZ's its quite convenient. However why should i not use it for production code?
Is it buggy?

Comment: To quickly show where the problem is in one line of code I made a dirty hack. If you instead replace `wx.ALIGN_CENTER` with `wx.EXPAND` when `.Add()`ing `img_box/doc_box` sizers, this is of course ok.